# Load .csv file in drop down list (search field) - how to?

Tags: javascript, csv

I'm more a designer than a developer. With this being said, here's my question:
Anyone knows how to fill a search field (first item) in a drop down list with content from a .csv file?

I have made a [website](https://www.findyourplumber.ca) and I want to add values (all municipalities from the site plan) from a .csv file that loads when I search a region from my drop down. I guess you will understand when you see the example on my homepage.

The issue at the moment is that the drop down list search tool only suggests items from the menu (list). I would like to add the possibility to search a .csv file and suggest items from that file (all municipalities from our site plan... There are about 300 municipalities). So when the user would start typing a municipality... Montreal for example, the list would show all municipalities starting with Montreal... Like Montreal-Est... Montreal-Ouest... Etc.  These are not in the menu (list) but would be in the .csv file.

Comment: Hey guys!  I added some JS to my script and it works... You can see my website in my earlier message. Thanks!